# how to custom country code picker layout to fit my design?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I tried putting it in a container but it does not work I tried also stack but it does not work
I want it like the photo attached

[image]

```dart
 Container(

                              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.black, width: 1)),
                              child: CountryCodePicker(

                                onChanged: (country) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    dialCodeDigits = country.dialCode!;
                                  });
                                },
                                initialSelection: 'دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة',
                                showCountryOnly: true,
                                showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: true,
                                favorite: ['+971', 'UAE', '+966', 'KSA'],
                                //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: ),
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xff000000),
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    wordSpacing: 5),
                                enabled: true,
                                // alignLeft: false,
                                  flagWidth: 28,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),



                              ),
                            ),
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: are you try to get the last image as outPut?

Comment: yes  i do , I want  it as the same picture

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column and add the country picker as the first element and then the phone number section as the second element to the column widget.

Please check this

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var check = getIndexFromNestedList(relatives);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  CountryCodePicker(
                    onChanged: (country) {
                      setState(() {
                        //dialCodeDigits = country.dialCode!;
                      });
                    },
                    initialSelection: 'دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة',
                    showCountryOnly: true,
                    showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: true,
                    favorite: ['+971', 'UAE', '+966', 'KSA'],
                    //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: ),
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff000000), fontSize: 14, wordSpacing: 5),
                    enabled: true,
                    // alignLeft: false,
                    flagWidth: 28,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined)
                ],
              ),
              Divider(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 50,
                        child: Text("+971"),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: "some hint here"),
                      ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview]